# After submitting form a part of the form is not loading php,html

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with some `datalist` tag for which the values are loaded from database. when the page is opened everything works fine but after submitting the form the code after the `datalist` is not working.

[image: Before Submission]

After Submission

[image: After Submission]

My Code

```
<label> Place</label>
 <input list="places" name="place" value="<?php echo $place;?>"><br/>
 <datalist id="places">
    <?php
        $result=$conn->query("SELECT vchr_place FROM tbl_academy_admission");
        $opt_places="";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $opt_places.="<option value='".$row['vchr_place']."'>";
        }
        echo $opt_places;
    ?>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

No options to the datalist tag will result in datalist not displayed.

Are you sure the query is returning records? try adding `<option value="Test">` before your php tag. If the options is displayed then that's the issue.